# Writing a method for a custom element in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm new to Polymer.js and I'm trying to implement an app-drawer; this is what I have so far:

```
<app-header reveals>
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="_toggleDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title>Title</div>
    <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>

<app-drawer id="drawer" opened={{drawerOpened}} swipe-open tabindex="0">
</app-drawer>
```

(`<paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="drawer.toggle()">` did not work [1](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/demo/app-drawer-layout/demo/index.html))

    .

```
class MyDrawer extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-drawer'; }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: 'my-drawer'
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Assuming this toggle method is correct:

```
_toggleDrawer: function() {
  this.drawerOpened = !this.drawerOpened;
}
```

, what's the correct syntax for Polymer 2.0 and where exactly do I place this method?

Or is there a simpler way to toggle the drawer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the function inside the class that extends the `Polymer.Element` base class.

In `Polymer 2` you can define a function as:

```
functionName(parameters if any){
   //definition goes here
}
```

> Note: If you use a single underscore `(_functionName)`, it will be a protected method or function and if you use double underscore `(__functionName)` it will be the private method or function to the  class.

In your code above, you can simply add the function inside class:

```
class MyDrawer extends Polymer.Element {

  static get is() { return 'my-drawer'; }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: 'my-drawer'
      }
    };
  }

  _toggleDrawer() {
      this.drawerOpened = !this.drawerOpened;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! When I added the `_toggleDrawer()` function though, the entire toolbar disappears. What gives?

Comment: Check the demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4w493w?p=preview. The toolbar is behind the drawer.

Comment: Ahhh I removed the `: function` in my `_toggleDrawer` function and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `drawer-toggle` attribute to your `<paper-icon-button>`

```
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work :( The drawer still doesn't show up when I click on the menu icon.

Comment: Can you compare with one of the demos (2, 3, 4, 5, 7 by peeking the source with your browser's dev tool), and find out what's wrong with your tags layout?
 https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/demo/demo/index.html